# import wallet from geth to myEtherWallet

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet

I created a wallet using geth (1.6.0-stable).
I can unlock it using geth: The command `personal.unlockAccount(address)` asks for the password and returns true.

But when I use https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info I get the error message "Invalid password. Error: Key derivation failed - possibly wrong passphrase"

I upload the only keystore from ~/.ethereum/keystore and copy the exact same password...

It seems the keystore file (UTC/JSON) formats are different between geth and myEtherWallet...

**Please do you confirm?
How should I import the wallet?**

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted way should work - I just tried it with the latest geth and MEW. In case you have an old version of geth, upgrade it first and then set the password to something simpler (it seems you have a simple password typo). You can change the password of an existing account via `geth account update [ENTER ADDRESS WITHOUT 0x HERE]`. Then try again in MEW.

Comment: Thanks for your help. geth definitely does not work on my machine (ubuntu). I had updated my password several times using geth. Hopefully I kept trak of the passwords. I succeeded to import the wallet in MEW with the very first passord! I'm done with geth, will try parity.