# How to get a private key of an encoded account which was created with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, private-key

I have next problem:
I have created an account with password via geth. Right now I need to get private keys (or somehow retrieve my eth) without starting a peer-to-peer node. Is it possible to retrieve the private key or send eth to a different address without starting peer-to-peer node and eth? I have keystore with the needed account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you unable to start `geth` at all for this question? Or do you just not want to sync? If you can start `geth`,  then you can [import your keys](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15923/import-wallet-from-geth-to-myetherwallet) into [MyEtherWallet](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/should-i-use-any-ethereum-wallet-listed-on-your-search-engine-or-advertisments) and send an off-line transaction.